# Making a call to Stripe API (to pause payment collection) using plain fetch, getting 400 response code

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I have this code:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

test("y", async () => {
    // const username = "rk_test_xyz"
    const encoded = Buffer.from(`${username}:`, 'utf-8').toString('base64')

    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append('pause_collection[behaviour]', 'void');

    const response = await fetch('https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscriptions/sub_1LFkzDH2RPqITCMjvjz9RCOJ', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: params,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Basic ${encoded}`,
            "Content-type": `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
        }
    });
    const status = response.status
    console.log({status})
})
```

When I run it I get status code 400.  What is wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple spelling mistake.  Should be `behavior` instead of `behaviour`.

And for anyone debugging Stripe API failures, the Stripe API dashboard gives good error messages on the Logs view at https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs